# Accessing compiled routes in Grape / Rack::Mount::Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, ruby-1.9, grape-api

I'm trying to generate a list of all routes generated by my subclass of Grape::API (MyApi).

I can get close by calling:

```
MyApi.send(:route_set).instance_variable_get(:@routes)
```

which gives me an array of Rack::Mount::Route objects.

The only attribute of the Route object that is useful is :conditions which returns a Hash like this:

```
 :path_info => (?-mix:\\A\\/api\\/(?<version>v1)\\/token(?:\\.(?<format>[^\\/]+))?\\Z)", "k: request_method, v: (?-mix:\\AGET\\Z)
```

As you can see the value of the hash is a regexp for matching the route's path.  I can also use :named_captures to get all the named captures from the regexp:

```
{:path_info=>{:version=>0, :format=>1}, :request_method=>{}}
```

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is generate a list of all routes created through Grape::API, their full path, etc.  It doesn't make sense to me to try and deconstruct the regexp in conditions.  Is there another way of accessing/generating a human readable path for Rack::Mount::Route?

Answer (score 7):

See this post [rake routes with grape](http://hermes-vertigem.herokuapp.com/2013/04/02/rake-routes-no-grape/)

basicaly you can get routes with:

```
MyApi.routes
```

UPDATE:

Article in English: [rake routes command on grape gem](http://dukex.svbtle.com/rake-routes-command-on-grape-gem)

Comment: that link is down, and it's to a .xxx domain? Hmmm

Comment: Yes is down @sardaukar, but you can acess here http://hermes-vertigem.herokuapp.com/2013/04/02/rake-routes-no-grape/ I fix on answer, Thankx

Answer (score 3):

If you are using grape with rails, check out the [grape_on_rails_routes](https://github.com/syedmusamah/grape_on_rails_routes) gem.

You can run `rake grape:routes` and see a nicely formatted list all current API's and their details (url, description, version).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11712383)

Comment: @RickyA thanks for the feedback;just updated the answer!

Comment: This method is better because it does not base on the project name, but searches through ObjectSpace for all the inheriting from Grape::API.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another variation to the answers here. I use the following two rake tasks.

```
task :all_routes => [:routes, :api_routes]

task :api_routes => :environment do
  longest_uri  = MyAPI.routes.map{|api|api.route_path.length}.max
  longest_desc = MyAPI.routes.map{|api|api.route_description.length}.max
  pattern = "%10s %-#{longest_uri}s %-#{longest_desc}s\n"

  # print column headers
  printf(
    pattern,
    "Verb", "URI Pattern", "Description"
  )

  # print each column
  MyAPI.routes.each do |api|
    printf(
      pattern,
      api.route_method, api.route_path, api.route_description
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How I did it:

```
desc "Print out routes"
task :routes => :environment do
  StudyTube::API::V1::Base.routes.each do |route|
    info = route.instance_variable_get :@options
    description = "%-40s..." % info[:description][0..39]
    method = "%-7s" % info[:method]
    puts "#{description}  #{method}#{info[:path]}"
  end
end
```

Prints them out nicely. I was futzing around with the truncation, but you can get rid of that if you want of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Once the route has been compiled it becomes something much less inspectable. Instead of reverse engineering it, see https://github.com/intridea/grape/pull/48/.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with one of the custom rake tasks if not running Rails. 
If you are in fact using Rails, take a look at the [grape-rails-routes gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/grape-rails-routes/versions/1.0).

It gives you a similar rake task `rake routes_with_grape`.

It's added value is however the html table view in the rails info section at `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes_with_grape`